# Clean URL using index files or mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

Is it better to make clean URL's using index files in directories or simply using `mod_rewrite` rules to remove the file extensions?

Comment: Whatever helps to keep you organized. If you have lots of pages you're gonna hate having lots of directories.

Comment: How would you propose to implement the "index files in directories" in order to make clean URLs?

Comment: Just read up on mod_rewrite to come up with the solution that best fits __you__.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to remove file extensions in order to create "clean URL's" as a URL with a file extension is no messier than one without a file extension. If you absolutely need to remove the file extensions then it is easier to use mod_rewrite as you won't need to create such a complex directory structure to achieve what files can achieve instead. As a side note if you use mod_rewrite and use a basic rule to remove the file extension you will need to make sure that all the files in question have the same file extension (ie: all files are .html files) otherwise you will need to create a separate rule for each file.